# Guides not aligning to artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, guides

I am using Adobe Illustrator CC 2015.2 and  trying to align guides to artboard but instead of artboard, guides are intersecting at the right corner of of the whole document page. like this

[image]

I checked *align to artboard*  and nothing is checked in Transform panel. 
I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! General, technical support questions are off topic for this site. You will also need to include more information for us to give you any advice. i.e. what operating system are you using? Does this happen with other objects? Have you clicked on one of the Align / Distribute buttons after you select "Align to Artboard"?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. "Use preview bounds" was checked, unchecked it and guide alignment now works fine. :)